# Create Outlook appointment via C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, iis-7.5, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to create an Outlook appointment using `microsoft.office.interop.outlook`, however while I can get it to work locally on my own workstation and it also works if I run the web application via the server's browser, it does not work when I connect to the server externally.

Hence, I think it might be a permission issue.

I changed the `application pool identity` to "`LocalSystem`" So now I don't get an access denied error. Unfortunately, it doesn't actually work.

The app behaves as if the appointment was successfully created, but the appointment doesn't appear in Outlook.

Here is my include file on top of my aspx.cs page

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

Here is the code I am using to pop up the appointment.

```
Outlook.Application apptApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.AppointmentItem appt = 
      apptApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem) as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
appt.Subject = txtFirstName.Text + " " + txtLastName.Text;
appt.Body = txtComment.Text;
appt.AllDayEvent = false;
appt.Start = DateTime.Parse(txtReminderDate.Text + " 8:00 AM");
appt.End = DateTime.Parse(txtReminderDate.Text + " 9:00 AM");
appt.Display(false);
```

As I said it works if I use `localhost` on the server, but if I try to access the app externally via another machine it does nothing.

I did install `Outlook 2003` on the server to get access to the interop.outlook file and added a reference to  `microsoft.office.core`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Set up the authorization access in your web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

In case it helps, I use the following method to create Outlook appointments:

```
private void CreateOutlookGroupMeetingAppointment(List<string> emailRecipients, string meetingPlace, string shortDescription, string longDescription, DateTime start, DateTime finish)
{
    try
    { 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application ApplicationInstance = null;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem AppointmentInstance = null;

        ApplicationInstance = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

        AppointmentInstance = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem) ApplicationInstance.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);

        foreach (string EmailRecipient in emailRecipients)
        {
            AppointmentInstance.Recipients.Add(EmailRecipient);

        }

        AppointmentInstance.Subject = shortDescription;

        AppointmentInstance.Body = longDescription;

        AppointmentInstance.Location = meetingPlace;

        AppointmentInstance.Start = start;

        AppointmentInstance.End = finish;

        AppointmentInstance.ReminderSet = true;

        AppointmentInstance.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15;

        AppointmentInstance.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;

        AppointmentInstance.BusyStatus = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olBusy;

        AppointmentInstance.Save();

        AppointmentInstance.Send();

    }
    catch //(Exception ex)
    {
        //ex.HandleException();

    }

}
```

> I use .Net 4.5, and reference the extension (Project => Add reference) called, 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook' (Version 15.0.0.0, File version 15.0.4420.1017)

Answer (score 0):

No Office app (Outlook included) can be used in a service (including IIS).

Your options are

1. In case of an Exchange Server, use [EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx) to access the mailbox.
2. Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only)
3. [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author, any language) - it wraps Extended MAPI and its [RDO](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) family of objects can be used from a service.

Comment: Well all it does is it creates an outlook appointment and initiates outlook on the client side with prefilled values. I tested it on a local machine and it works. The client still has to accept the schedule and click on "save" when the even is triggered. The above code works if performed on the local box.

Comment: If your code is running in a service, how would the user be able to see the displayed appointment?

Comment: Sorry not a service a webpage (aspx.cs not asmx) page.

Comment: Your ASP code is running in the context of IIS, which is a service. And you create an appointment and display it on the server, where there is nobody to see it. You can run your code in JavaScript on the client side, but then you are limited to EI *if* your site is in the trusted list

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using outlook interop, you should try using EWS (exchange web services). As for your current problem, what credentials is your service running under when you deploy it to the external machine ? We have run into issues where you/your machine has access to the outlook server hence when you run it locally, everything works. However, when you deploy it to a machine, it runs under different credentials that do not have the appropriate permissions.

Comment: I changed the application pool for that website to localsystem I figured that would be sufficient, I read that perhaps its a dcom config setting, but can't find outlook on there.

Comment: You could try running the application  pool as you and see if that fixes the issue